# requiring records to exist if they exist in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is currently kind of melting my brain, but there's got to be a way to do it. Basically the query looks like this:

```
SELECT r.* FROM records r
JOIN users u ON u.job_id = r.job_id  
LEFT JOIN records_requirements rr ON rr.record_id = r.id
INNER JOIN user_requirements ur on ur.requirement_id = rr.requirement_id
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is say get all the records that have the same job id as the user and if the record has requirements only select them if the user has a matching record in the user_requirements table. If the user does not have the requirement, then do not select the record.

So get all the records that have the same job_id and no requirements, or have the same job_id and do not any have requirements that the user does not have.

Comment: Something like where requirements ID = record ID

Comment: I\`m guessing you need an anti-join,a `WHERE blah IS NULL` check

Comment: Like `WHERE (rr.requirement_id IS NULL OR ur.requirement_id IS NOT NULL)` ? Would this work if there were multiple rr.requirement_ids? I still only want to pull one record even if it has a bunch of record requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing it, I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM records r
INNER JOIN users u ON u.job_id = r.job_id
LEFT JOIN records_requirements rr ON rr.record_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN user_requirements ur ON ur.requirement_id = rr.requirement_id 
  AND ur.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
  (
    (rr.record_id IS NULL) 
      OR 
    (rr.record_id IS NOT NULL AND ur.requirement_id IS NOT NULL)
  )
  AND u.id = ?
```

What it's doing is left joining to record requirements to allow for no requirements, but also then left joining to user requirements so that records with requirements but no matching user requirements are still pulled.

Then a where test is used to allow for either null record requirements, or both record and user requirements being in place.

Finally, SELECT DISTINCT is used to ensure you only get one result per record.

Edit: a quick test using SQL Server as follows:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (job_id int)
DECLARE @Records TABLE (id int, job_id int)
DECLARE @Records_Requirements TABLE (requirement_id int, record_id int)
DECLARE @User_Requirements TABLE (requirement_id int)

INSERT INTO @Users VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO @Records VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Records VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO @Records VALUES (3, 1)

INSERT INTO @Records_Requirements VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Records_Requirements VALUES (2, 2)

INSERT INTO @User_Requirements VALUES (2)

SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM @Records r
INNER JOIN @Users u ON u.job_id = r.job_id
LEFT JOIN @Records_Requirements rr ON rr.record_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN @User_Requirements ur on ur.requirement_id = rr.requirement_id
WHERE (rr.record_id IS NULL) OR (rr.record_id IS NOT NULL AND ur.requirement_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Resulted in:

```
id  job_id
2   1
3   1
```

Which I think is correct for the test data. Perhaps MySQL works differently, though it shouldn't.

Comment: I actually came to be doing something just like this, but it fails if there is no record_requirement, presumably because the LEFT JOIN doesn't see any rr.requirement_id. Edit: It shows the record if the record_requirement exists and the user requirement exists and match, shows no match if rr.requirement_id is not null and ur. requirement_id is null as it should however.

Comment: I've done a quick test using SQL Server (I don't have MySQL to hand), and it seemed to work as expected. Are you able to provide a short script to create some test data? (I'll paste my SQL test into my answer for reference)... or could you provide some test data and expected results?

Comment: I spent a lot o time trying to figure out why it doesn't work and it turns out the reason was not what I thought, the reason was that the ur.requirement_id does not have to be associated with the particular user (should have included that i'm looking for records that match a particular user) and so needed to add a way to link to the particular user. having `ur.user_id = ?` was breaking it, so i had to move a clause to the ON clause, unless you know of a way to do a `WHERE ur.user_id = ? or ur.user_id is null` or something in the where clause but that seems dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this! I will accept your answer, but could you edit it to show it finding the records that match for a certain user?

Comment: I did wonder about that - the table structure seemed like it was missing a link somewhere :). I've added what I think should work to restrict to a single user.